# <div> created through jquery not getting styled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a grid of square `div`s using `jquery`. The problem is that even though all the columns and their content get created, the last column's `div`s does not get styled resulting in a zero height/width `div`.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var column = $("<div class='column'></div>");
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>");
      $('.unit').css("width", (960 / 4));
      $('.unit').css("height", (960 / 4));
      column.append(unit);
    }
    $("#container").append(column);
  }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.unit {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 1px;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the defined variable `unit` which you have created instead `$('.unit')`

```
var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>");
unit.css("width", (960 / 4));
unit.css("height", (960 / 4));
column.append(unit);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var column = $("<div class='column'></div>");
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>");
      unit.css("width", (960 / 4));
      unit.css("height", (960 / 4));
      column.append(unit);
    }
    $("#container").append(column);
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.unit {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 1px;
}
.column {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I was going to suggest appending the new `div` before attempting to read it from the DOM, but this seems more efficient :)

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer my question.